# What is the expected behaviour of browsers when using cache-control?

Tags: html, caching, browser

I have Apache server, which is sending `Cache-Control:max-age=290304000, private` in headers.

Now I opened the site (twice) in 3 browsers, and got different result each time-

1. Firefox 28 - In firebug net tab, I saw no new content getting downloaded (except `index.html`). Not even 304 (not modified) responses. So I believe it is caching properly.
2. Chrome 34 - In network tab, I saw that most of the files are taken from cache (see screenshot below). But some are downloaded. This is confusing me because, it should behave same for all the content.
3. IE 10 - All images, js and css are attempted to be downloaded (returned with 304).

[image]

So my questions are-

1. why is chrome downloading some files, instead of taking them from cache? (additionally why wasn't response 304?)
2. Why is IE downloading all the files?